# Actual difference between Value Objects and Entities. DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities, value-objects

Domain-Driven Design, I'm trying to figure out what the difference some kind of mathematically and not intuitively. In my current project, we have some kind of `payment` transfers between `banks`.
In this system, the bank is carried not like a physical building but an abstract `bank`. It has `BankCode` for sure, `country` and `Bank Name`. And the question is: `Is the bank should be an entity or value object`. I intuitively feel that it should be entity, but some people say that it could be like a value object.

As I know, `entities` MIGHT have the same attributes but still be different. On the other hand, `value objects` must not have an `identity`, they should be the same in case all attributes are the same, they should answer what they are, not who or which they are. Please If I'm wrong - correct me.

In the system, `banks` are not changing during any flow, like another Value object `Country` or `Currency`, probably we could say, that banks with the same bank code, name, and country are the same banks. As well as we can say that `Country` with the same country code (ISO format) is the same. But still, for me, I feel like they are entities. Could someone prove where I'm wrong, and give mathematic proofs that they should be either `Value` object or `Entities`.

Currently, I end up with that: "`The one difference between Entity and Value Object is the entity can contain the all same attributes and still be different, the Value Object can't`", like transaction and people can have same amounts and goods, same names, but still be different, and like address should be the same if the country, city, and house number are the same. Please correct me, and maybe there are more differences

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your replies, guys, it became much more cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic example difference between the two, is based on the context (as DDD always is), so lets go for it...

Classic Example: An airplane flight (allocated seat or any seat)...

### Entity

Each seat has a number, and you allocate a passenger a specific seat (Seat: 10 E)

### Value Object

The plane has a number of seats, and you give a passenger 1 (or more) seat(s), on the plane (non specific, sit anywhere).

The key question is, do you care about the individual entity (a seat) or just the total number of available seats?

You can see the DDD - context separation here, even if you allocate seats, not every context is going to care.  If I'm doing a capacity piece, I don't care about the entities, I just want to know

```cs
var unused = available - used.
```

---

### Your initial Question

#### Simple Answer

It's an entity

#### Deeper Answer

It depends on the context.

#### And then...

In some contexts it may be a Domain Model in itself, like your context.

If I want to move money from Bank1 and Bank2 then, I'm going to do...

```cs
// Both domain models
Bank sendingBank = _bankStore.Get(fromBank.Id);
Bank receivingBank = _bankStore.Get(toBank.Id);

_moneyTransfer(sendingBank, receivingBank, amount);
```

#### Or alternatively

Calling code

```cs
Customer customer = _customerStore.Get(customerId);

var balanace = customer.GetBalance();
```

Entity Version: Customer

```cs
public class Customer {
    public Bank {get; private set;}

    public Decimal GetBalance () {
       return this.Bank.GetBalance();
    }
}
```

Value Object Version: Customer

```cs
public class Customer {
   public Balance {get; private set;}

   public Customer (..., decimal bankBalance) {
      this.Balance = bankBalance;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is the bank should be an entity or value object

A prior question to ask is: do you need to model the bank?

In particular, do you control the rules by a which a bank changes?  Or are you just managing a local cache/repository of information that is provided to you by some other authority (in the same way that country code information is provided to us by the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency).

An important principle in domain driven design is to take the care to ensure that you are modeling the thing that you are supposed to be modeling.

> we could say, that banks with the same bank code, name, and country are the same banks. As well as we can say that Country with the same country code (ISO format) is the same. But still, for me, I feel like they are entities.

Yes.  Banks are certainly entities.  So are countries.

But they are real world entities.  Your domain model doesn't own them.  What you have in your data store is locally cached information about those entities.

For example, the ISO-3166-1 standard is a living document; it was changed as recently as 2020-03-02 (a correction to the full names for MK).  A given country code *and date* gives you a fixed identifier.  Because country codes are reserved for 50 years, the country code alone is unambiguous for non trivial time periods.

The token `MK` is certainly a value object.  The lookup table that says token `MK` means `North Macedonia` is an entity.  But... it is a stable entity, so in some contexts we might be able to treat it as fixed.

(That's a general property of standardized identifiers - standards are worthless if they aren't adopted, so the change management policies are designed to make things easy for adopters).

Unless you are yourself doing work for ISO 3166/MA, though, it isn't *your* entity.  The information you have is just a copy.

My guess is that's true of your bank codes as well.

Part of the point of domain driven design: that if we do the work to make sure that we really understand the actual business problem that we are trying to model, then our subsequent implementation will be well aligned with what we want, and easy to change in the face of new requirements.

Which is to say, you really need to make sure you understand "bank" in the context of your domain to determine if it is an entity or a value object.

Comment: thank you for the response. Yes, we don't own banks it's just like cache or repository. But did I correctly understand, that it means they are value objects then if we got them from some source like ISO?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `bank` should be an **Entity** as each bank has a unique `BankCode` to identify it. Even if at this point your system doesn't update banks, it doesn't mean that it won't be possible in the future.

If some attribute of the bank changes, for example, it's main office address (just made it up...) of whatever else you got changes, the code that uniquely identifies it will remain the same, hence the same bank, but with a different main office address.

This bank `BankCode: 1234, Location: US Texas` and this bank after a change in the `Location` attribute `BankCode: 1234, Location: US Colorado` is still the same thing.

Giving a mathematical definition is difficult because mathematics is about ***values***.

This kind of uniqueness based ***not on attributes*** but on some kind of **Identity** that remains the same as it changes is closer to how the real world works, so it's difficult to give non-intuitive definitions of it.

Here's a good example of a `ValueObject` from math. Let's say you model a 3D math library with vectors and matrices. `Vector` and `Matrix` are `ValueObjects`.

Let's say that we have two vectors:

- v1 -> x = 1, y = 2, z = 3
- v2 -> x = 1, y = 2, z = 3

You do have two vectors, but from a math point of view, they are identical i.e. represent the same thing and are equal. The same applies to matrices.

Let's have a transformation T (translation for example). In math what you have is:

v3 = T (v1, v2)

You get a brand new vector when you apply this transformation. This brand we vector may have the same coordinates as v1 and v2 as a result so they will be equal, but you ***do not change*** v1 or v2.

Let's say you get a hair cut and let's say that this is a transformation too. If this true in the real world?

You2 = T(Hairdresser, You1)

No, it's not. It' still you with a different hair cut, you do not create a different you when you apply the transformation.

A good example of when a concept can be both a value and an entity depending on the system is when modeling `Money`. In your case when you make bank transfers, you transfer money between accounts. In this case, `Money` is a `ValueObject` because you do not case to differentiate between 5$ and 5$, it's still the same ***amount***.

Let's say you go to a store to buy a drink, This drink is 5$. If you have two `Banknotes` of 5$, it doesn't matter which one you use to pay because they represent the same ***amount***.

On the other hand, each `Banknote` has a serial number. The two 5$ `Banknotes` will have different serial numbers making them unique and different, so they are `Entities`.

If your system tracks `Banknotes` then you model it as an `Entity`. If not, you model it as a `ValueObject`.

Do vectors and matrices have serial numbers on them or any kind of Identity? Your car (if you have one) does. If you go to a parking lot with lots of cars and you have two cars yours and some else's car, that are exactly the same, do you care which one you take? Well, it's better to take yours, otherwise, it stealing and it's against the law and someone won't be happy about it.

Let's take our vectors again and the transformation T.

T(v1, v2), T(v2, v2), and T(v1, v1) all give the same result because these two vectors are equal and we do not care which one we use.

Comment: I can understand why the bank is an entity, because, since the bank codes are the same - the banks are the same. Once bank codes are not the same, even if other attributes are the same - the entities are different. But then I confused about Currency Value object. The situations are similar. And one reason why currency for me is Value Object is that it has only currency code, that identifies each currency. Since currency has no other properties which can be the same for different currencies. But the bank could have e.g. bank name the same for different banks, so it is an entity. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, depending. Why? Because it depends what you want from the currency.  If you're just recording the currency type its a value, if you're modelling currency with exchange rates - then it could be an entity. Currency Type is different to a Currency - depending on the context (always context :D).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, i could explain the question at another aspect. Entity usually has a identify, but what does the identity used to do? I think it used to trace the entity state changing. Why we should trace the state changing? Because the entity is referenced by other context/object according identify.

That's why we said that it depends on the specific context/case. For some context, we don't care the state changing, it will be Value Object, otherwise it will be Entity.

The Address often regarded as Value Object. You entered your address on a shopping website, the address will not be refered by your family members when they logging in the same the system, even if all of you have the same address.

But when you browsing, modifing or deleting the address entered before, it must be a Entity, becuase it is referred by Address Editor and Address Book with identify.

When an Adress used by an order, it will be an Object Value or Entity depends on the Address should be changed when Address Book changed.